# Unknown attribute 'answered_questions_attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a form where a user can answer questions and submit to a results page, however, when I am trying to pass the AnsweredQuestions attributes through the Quiz controller it's telling me it's an 'unknown attribute'.

Error i'm receving: unknown attribute 'answered_questions_attributes' for AnsweredQuestion.

Quiz.rb:

```
 class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answered_questions, through: :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answered_questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

AnsweredQuestion.rb:

```
class AnsweredQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :quiz
end
```

Quiz controller:

```
  def show
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all
    @answered_questions = current_user.answered_questions.build

    @quiz.answered_questions.build

  end

  def create 
    @quiz = Quiz.new(show_params)
    if @quiz.save
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new quiz!"
      redirect_to @quiz
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def post_answered_questions 
    @answered_question = current_user.answered_questions.build(show_params)
    if @answered_question.save
      flash[:success] = "You have completed the quiz!"
      redirect_to results_quiz_path(params[:quiz][:id])
    else
      render ''
    end
  end

  private

  def user_completed_quiz 
    if(current_user.answered_questions.pluck(:quiz_id).uniq.include?(params[:id].to_i)) 
      redirect_to quizzes_path
    end
  end

  def show_params
    params.require(:quiz).permit(:title, answered_questions_attributes: [:id, :answer_id, :question_id, :user_id, :quiz_id], questions_attributes: [:id, :question_title, :quiz_id, :done, :_destroy, answers_attributes: [:id, :answer_title, :question_id, :quiz_id, :correct_answer, :_destroy]])
  end
end
```

show.html.erb (in quizzes):

```
<%= form_for(@quiz, url: post_answered_questions_quizzes_path, method: "POST") do |f| %>

<%= @quiz.title %>

<%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => @quiz.id %>

<% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>

<%= f.fields_for :answered_questions do |answer_ques| %>

    <h4><%= question.question_title %></h4>

        <%= answer_ques.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
        <%= answer_ques.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
        <%= answer_ques.select(:answer_id, options_for_select(question.answers.map{|q| [q.answer_title, q.id]})) %>

    <% end %>


    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag %>

    <% end %>
```

UPDATED:

show.html.erb (quizzes):

```
<%= form_for(@answered_questions, url: answered_questions_path, method: "POST") do |f| %>

<%= @quiz.title %>

<%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => @quiz.id %>

<% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>

<%= f.fields_for :answered_questions do |answer_ques| %>

    <h4><%= question.question_title %></h4>

        <%= answer_ques.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
        <%= answer_ques.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
        <%= answer_ques.select(:answer_id, options_for_select(question.answers.map{|q| [q.answer_title, q.id]})) %>

    <% end %>


    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag %>

    <% end %>
```

AnsweredQuestion controller:

```
class AnsweredQuestionsController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @answered_question = AnsweredQuestion.new
  end

  def create
    @answered_question = current_user.answered_questions.build(answered_params)
    binding.pry
    if @answered_question.save
      flash[:success] = "You have completed the quiz!"
      redirect_to results_quiz_path(params[:quiz][:id])
    else
      render ''
    end
  end

  def edit
    @answered_questions = AnsweredQuestion.find(params[:id])
  end


  def destroy
    AnsweredQuestion.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Answered quiz deleted"
    redirect_to answered_questions_url
  end

  private


  def answered_params
    params.require(:answered_questions).permit(:question_id, :answer_ids, :user_id, :quiz_id, :id, :_destroy)
  end

end
```

Comment: Why are you trying to save a record for `AnsweredQuestion` through `Quiz`? That logic should go in it's own controller. Also the relationships are not set-up correctly, `Quiz` has many `Question` has many `QuestionAnswered`, so `QuestionAnswered` should not belong to `Quiz` directly, that is causing denormalization.

Comment: I originally had it in it's own controller but when I do this it then says that the answered_questions param is empty, i've updated the post to reflect what it looks like now i've given it it's own controller

Comment: I don't see anything wrong... can you post the result of calling `answered_params` method inside the create action?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are accepting nested attributes for `Quiz` but using the nested attributes in `AnsweredQuestion` instead of in `Quiz`. You need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the other model and in `show_params` it should be `quiz_attributes` instead of `answered_questions_attributes`. Although you are using `show_params` twice, once over one model and the second one over the other, so you may need two params. Otherwise you'll break the other one.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the form as well, not sure what you mean? I'm just trying to pass the answered questions parameters in the quiz controller

Comment: `current_user.answered_questions.build(show_params)` <- here you are using the `AnsweredQuestion` model, which I guess is what fails. Isn't it?

Comment: I tried changing this around so it was for quiz instead of answered questions and it's not still working